# Ubuntu boots to black screen when VGA monitor connected

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have installed Ubuntu (tried 18.04 and 19.10) on a Lenovo ThinkCenter M710e. It has VGA and DisplayPort outputs. If I plug a monitor into the VGA port then Ubuntu boots to a black screen on both monitors. Using `nomodeset` gets me a graphical desktop.

Without the VGA connected it boots up just fine and uses the DisplayPort monitor. It's the same with a live session; I have to use safe graphics mode if the VGA monitor is connected, otherwise I just get a black screen.

Here is `lspci`:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
```

Dual monitors work in the pre-installed windows 10, so I'm pretty sure it's not a hardware problem.

Ubuntu doesn't show any third party drivers available to install. I would really like to get the dual monitors working but I'm not sure where to go from here.

What steps can I take to determine what needs to be done to make the dual monitors work?

Answer (score 0):

For intel graphics there are no third party or proprietary drivers.

The `xrandr` tool can be most useful for diagnosing multi-monitor issues.  Your /var/log/Xorg.0.log file (or similar) often gives info about which outputs are detected or not detected, and why.

First thing I'd suggest is to check your BIOS for any multi-monitor related settings.  Make sure the intel graphics is your primary graphics device.  See:

```
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht062228
```

Also make sure you're using the Displayport monitor as the primary, with VGA secondary.  It sounds like it may not work the other way round:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkCentre-A-E-M-S-Series/Dual-monitors-problem-VGA-and-Displayport/td-p/338731

One other thing I would recommend investigating, is if your Laptop's displayport output, and your monitors support Displayport daisychaining.  This means you would connect the laptop to one monitor, and then from one monitor to the other.  Not all hardware combinations work like this, but if it does it will give better results than DP+VGA.  In my own brief googling I can find nothing definitive one way or the other.  You'll have to google around to find out more, but here's a link to get you started:

https://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/

If you do need to go with the VGA+DP route, and the above info doesn't sort it out for you, unfortunately there are all manner of different reasons things may not work.  VGA is an old tech and there's a lot of diversity in how standards are interpreted, both on the laptop end and on the monitor end.  Sometimes the monitor's EDID is not detected and so no modeline can be automatically constructed.  Sometimes it's an issue with mismatching refresh rates or incompatible resolutions; these can be worked through via sufficient elbow grease, but it can be technically challenging.  I've also seen situations where one output port is physically disabled by the HW when another output is in use (this should be mentioned in your laptop's manual under the graphics section); in this case there's simply no way to make the VGA+DP combo work.

The good news though is that IBM/Lenovo have a good reputation for supporting their hardware on Linux, and have helpful forums.  There's a subforum for ThinkCenters here:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkCentre-Desktops/ct-p/thinkcentre_en

Comment: Thanks! I will check into those links. I also edited my question to say that dual monitor VGA+DP works correctly in windows, which I think addresses your note about the possibility that one output may be disabled by the HW.